# Can not upgrade to python-2.4.3-43 on Red Hat Linux 5

Tags: linux, redhat, python, rpm

I'm trying to upgrade using package python-2.4.3-43.el5.x86_64.rpm, but everything I do so I get a failed dependency requirement for libpython2.4.so.1.0, but I've checked /usr/lib64 and the file is there. The current version of python that is installed is python-2.4.3.27.el5_5.3.x86_64.

Any idea why this may be failing to install when that libpython file actually exists?

Comment: what is the output of `rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/lib64/libpython*`?

Comment: python-libs-2.4.3-43.el5

Comment: what is the output of `rpm -Uvh python-2.4.3-43.el5.x86_64.rpm` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though this sounds like a 64-bit machine, there are often a lot of 32-bit dependencies.  Have you tried installing both x86_64 and i386 versions of the dependencies?

Comment: This is indeed a 64-bit machine and that has crossed my mind. Haven't tried it yet. That's something I'll give a go tomorrow.